# Replace table that has a referencing entity / cannot drop table ... because it is being referenced by object

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there an way to swap out a table with another table of the same name that's held under a different schema, that avoids causing issues with any referencing objects?

### More detail

I'm working on a script to refresh data in our test environment with data from another instance.
This script restores a backup from the ohter instance side by side with our test database, then copies those tables we want refreshed (a subset of the full set of tables) into a staging schema on our test database (the idea being that we can do this work without impacting the test system, so as to minimise downtime).

I then want to drop the table in the `dbo` schema and alter the `staging` schema's instance of the table to move it under the `dbo` schema.

I've disabled check constraints to avoid some potential issues this may cause, but when testing my script I got an error `Cannot DROP TABLE 'dbo.MyTable' because it is being referenced by object 'MyViewWithSchemaBinding'`.

Given my plan is to immediately replace this dropped table with a similar copy, is there any way to avoid this error without resorting to traversing the dependency graph & dropping all referencing objects?

NB: I could truncate data in the `dbo` table then overwrite it with data from the staging table, but that wouldn't be as performant, and there's a small possibility that the table's definition may differ (i.e. if the test environment is running a different version of code to what our backup used).
I'm willing to accept that when there are schema differences which break such dependencies things will fail - in most cases though I suspect any schema changes would be irrelevant.

Comment: If the table in staging has the same indexes and foreign keys as the dbo one has you may be able to partition switch the dbo to an empty table then partition switch from target to dbo

Comment: Thank-you; I'd not come across that before - reading up on it now.  https://database.guide/switch-out-a-partition-in-sql-server-t-sql/

Comment: But I've just realised that the table is being referenced by foreign keys, not other way round. In that case it won't help

Comment: You could re-script the views without schemabinding, and if you're lucky, it will work to drop the table and change it. Seems like a lot of busywork though.